# retrieve url from div class with javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm trying to retrieve the url from div class using javascript

```
<div class="img-cover" style="background-image: url('https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xta1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/11420829_845417035570963_433708785_n.jpg')"></div>
```

i have this page loaded into UIWebView on iOS, http://websta.me/popular

i try to retrieve all image's url, i looked up the source page and found that all images i need, are loaded into **div class** as background image, as example above

i used the document.getElementsByClass but doesn't work.

I want to implement this into an iOS app, to retrieve the image url from uiwebview and save into nsarray

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: @blm  NSString *someHTML = [MywebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('img-cover')[0].innerHTML;"];

    
    NSLog(@"Images : %@", someHTML);

Comment: Add that to the question, and also some indication of what that does. "doesn't work" isn't sufficient, be *specific*. However, I notice that you're using innerHTML and the example you have doesn't have any innerHTML.

Comment: @blm just edited the question

Answer (score 2):

To get string from `class` name:

```
NSString *someHTML = [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('class name')[0].innerHTML;"];
```

Comment: it doesn't work.. i replaced the 'class name' with img-cover and doest work.. maybe because i have a lot of classes with the same name?

Answer (score 0):

Going by the example `<div>` tag in the question, you want:

```
NSString *someHTML = [MywebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('img-co‌​ver')[0].style.backgroundImage;"];
```

The example code you gave in your comment is using `.innerHTML`. However, your example `<div>` tag doesn't have any inner HTML. Inner HTML is the HTML between the start and corresponding end tag, so if you had `<div>hello</div>`, the inner HTML, appearing in the `.innerHTML` property on that element, would be `hello`. In your example, the URL is actually in the `style` attribute of the `<div>`, so you want to get that with `.style`, then you want the `background-image` style, which is in the `backgroundImage` property of the `style` object.

Note however that the page you point to doesn't have the images in `<div>` tags, it has them in anchors (`<a>` tags), so you may have to modify that code slightly, but they still had the URL you want in the `background-image` style in the `style` attribute, so that part stays the same.

Comment: the string doesn't return any value.. i tried this: NSString *imageURLString = [MywebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"(function() {var images=document.getElementsByClassName('img-co‌​ver')[0].style.backgroundImage;var imageUrls=[];[].forEach.call(images, function(el) { imageUrls[imageUrls.length] = el.url;}); return JSON.stringify(imageUrls);})()"];

Comment: Are you sure the img-cover class is correct? When I look at the page you linked to in your question, there isn't anything with that class (the string doesn't appear anywhere in the page source at all). Here's what I see now: `<a href="..." title="Share on Tumblr" style="display:inline-block; text-indent:-9999px; overflow:hidden; width:81px; height:20px; background:url('http://platform.tumblr.com/v1/share_1.png') top left no-repeat transparent;"></a>` (I elided the href because it made the comment too long). Maybe try one step at a time, just get the element, see if that works, etc.

Answer (score -2):

This might be useful to retrieve what you're looking for:

var myLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

Give your div an ID like this:

Then in your script you can recall the URL with above and replace the 'a' with the name you chose for the div.

Comment: i don't have any 'a' tags. all i have is a lot of <div class="img-cover" style="background-image: url('https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xta1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/11420829_845417035570963_433708785_n.jpg')"></div> and i want to retrieve these urls